# Html2Canvas Resize

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas in an effort to get a screenshot of a webpage and render it as a thumbnail (well, 400x300, not exactly a thumbnail).

Based on the [Screenshot console code](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html), everything works great with the exception of the thumbnail part.

How can I set the image size to 400x300? In firebug I locate the attribute as: `<canvas style="width: 973px; height: 2184px;" width="973" height="2184"></canvas>`. However, I cannot figure out in my code(below) or in the html2canvas.js where to hardcode the 400x300 parameters.

**screenshot.html:**

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Screenshot</title> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
</script>
<![endif]--> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div class=container> </div> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var date=new Date();
var message,timeoutTimer,timer;
var proxyUrl="http://html2canvas.appspot.com";
function addRow(a,c,d){var b=$("<tr />").appendTo($(a));b.append($("<td />").css("font-weight","bold").text(c)).append($("<td />").text(d))}function throwMessage(b,a){window.clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);timeoutTimer=window.setTimeout(function(){message.fadeOut(function(){message.remove()})},a||2000);$(message).remove();message=$("<div />").html(b).css({margin:0,padding:10,background:"#000",opacity:0.7,position:"fixed",top:10,right:10,fontFamily:"Tahoma",color:"#fff",fontSize:12,borderRadius:12,width:"auto",height:"auto",textAlign:"center",textDecoration:"none"}).hide().fadeIn().appendTo("body")}$(function(){$("#recommended a").click(function(c){c.preventDefault();$("#url").val(this.href);$("button").click()});var a,b;$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){$(a.contentWindow).unbind("load");$(a).contents().find("body").html2canvas({canvasHeight:b.body.scrollHeight,canvasWidth:b.body.scrollWidth,logging:true})});$("#getscreenshot").click(function(d){d.preventDefault();$(this).prop("disabled",true);var c=$("#url").val();$("#content").append($("<img />").attr("src","loading.gif").css("margin-top",40));var f=document.createElement("a");f.href=c;$.ajax({data:{xhr2:false,url:f.href},url:proxyUrl,dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){a=document.createElement("iframe");$(a).css({visibility:"hidden"}).width($(window).width()/2).height($(window).height()/2);$("#content").append(a);b=a.contentWindow.document;b.open();$(a.contentWindow).load(function(){var g=$(a).contents().find("body"),h={onrendered:function(j){$("#content").empty().append(j);$("#getscreenshot").prop("disabled",false);$("base").attr("href","")},allowTaint:true,taintTest:false,flashcanvas:"src/flashcanvas.min.js"},i=html2canvas(g,h)});$("base").attr("href",f.protocol+"//"+f.hostname+"/"+f.pathname);e=e.replace("<head>","<head><base href='"+f.protocol+"//"+f.hostname+"/"+f.pathname+"'  />");if($("#disablejs").prop("checked")){e=e.replace(/\<script/gi,"<!--<script");e=e.replace(/\<\/script\>/gi,"<\/script>-->")}b.write(e);b.close()}})})});
</script> 

<form class="well form-search"> 
<label for=url>Website URL:</label> 
<input type=url id=url value="http://www.yahoo.com" class="input-medium search-query"/>
<button class=btn id=getscreenshot>Get screenshot!</button> 
</form> 

 <div id=content></div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create additional new `<canvas>` with thumbnail dimensions and use drawImage() to scale it down on this new `<canvas>`.

drawImage() can read `<canvas>` as `image` source and you may set target width and height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 23):

Based on Mikkos hint the following woked for me

```
window.html2canvas([$('body')[0]], {
              onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var extra_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                extra_canvas.setAttribute('width',70);
                extra_canvas.setAttribute('height',70);
                var ctx = extra_canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height,0,0,70,70);
                var dataURL = extra_canvas.toDataURL();
                var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
                img.attr('src', dataURL);
                // insert the thumbnail at the top of the page
                $('body').prepend(img);
              },
            });
```

Comment: Hello, your code got me so close to the success, just missing something with the ctx

I have an image with unknown width & height.

and i want it to fit (keeping its aspect ratio) in lets say 800x500 px

But when the image is widther i got an undesire cropped :(
Any idea how to setup a properly fit ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This works great for me...

```
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("divTextOrig"), { allowTaint: true, 
    scrollX:0, scrollY: -window.scrollY}).then(function(canvas)
    {
        document.getElementById("divText1").appendChild(canvas);
        $('canvas').css("width",txtWidth);
        $('canvas').css("height",txtHeight);                    
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar approach for your problem, partly based on other answers :) 
Since resizing images is easier if they are actual images, here is my code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
img.width = 500;
document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].appendChild(img);
```

`canvas`is the output of the html2canvas function; then I create an `img` setting its source with the img data (the base64 encoding of the canvas). the rest is standard good-old-javascript: set the img width, append to the div element ...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can get a reference from the canvas context by using the `getContext('2d')` method, then by assigning the returned context to a variable (for ex. `ctx`), you can be able to use the context `scale` method to scale the canvas context to the desired size. As an addition you can define the canvas size using the style attribute and setting the size of style `width` and `height` property by dividing the actual image size with the desired thumbnail size. In the last step you put the resulting number in the `ctx.scale(width, height);` method.

Answer (score 0):

found this way unexpactly for me(later i found why its do so). Just add few attributes after position attributes, like this `doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20, 200, 250)`, and two last number gives you the opportunity to resize img.