# Save div to Image (JS or PHP ?)

Tags: javascript, php, image-processing, html2canvas

I am working on something similar to this service http://admocks.adparlor.com/#facebook/video_post

User put some information in and get the download of a specific mockup with the information in it.

I have played around with html2cavas (https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) the result isn't that good. In cases where users resizes the window this approach fails.

I am wondering if there is a better way to save the content of a specific div server side ?

Does anybody have an idea how the above mentioned service do the trick ?

Comment: Off-topic, but "Hey Safari User! For the best experience, we advise you to use Google Chrome." ... what is this, 1995?

Comment: have you tried this approach while using html2canvas and resize events?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397785/html2canvas-resize