# html2canvas bigger size of download image

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I've set up **html2canvas** so I can edit text and then download that as image and that works great, but the size is limited to the width of its container.

If I set up canvas width and height render becomes that size but it's black. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yjpwsLv3/) with everything working but if you add width and height (currently commented), rendered pictured will get black.

JavaScript

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagewrap"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    canvas.className = "html2canvas";
    // canvas.width = "1080";
    // canvas.height = "1920";
    document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").appendChild(canvas);
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = image;
  },
  useCORS: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating a new `<canvas>` element and setting the `width` and `height` attributes, the image is drawn on the canvas using the `drawImage()` method <sup>[1]</sup>.

```js
html2canvas(document.getElementById("imagewrap"), {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    var  _canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    _canvas.setAttribute('width', 1080);
    _canvas.setAttribute('height', 1920);
    var ctx = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, 1080, 1920);
    var dataURL = _canvas.toDataURL();  
    document.getElementById("canvasWrapper").appendChild(_canvas);
    var image = _canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = image;
  },
  useCORS: true
});
```

Copy the JavaScript code below without disturbing your current work on JSFiddle and click the Download button to download the image. Then review the properties and content of the downloaded image:

[image]

---

<sup>1 - [Html2Canvas Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397785/html2canvas-resize/16304718)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your help. This did enlarge the image, but the resolution is blown up (it's blurry). I'm gonna try and figure out if there is some resolution parameter (I think I saw it in documentation) and report back here.

Comment: I think this issue may be the subject of a new question.

Comment: You have to change the `scale` parameter. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50736279/15032688)

Comment: Yeah, but it would be nice little complete solution for anyone in the future :) I went over 40+ examples until I paced image + editable text = downloadable image

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying that now

Comment: Neither scale or dpi seem to help. I've placed them before onrendered function and the result is the same.

Comment: I tried too; It seems normal that it doesn't work. Because the original image size is 1080x1920. This may be the limit value for us. However, there is one thing that draws attention. The original image size is **223 KB** but the image size we downloaded is **2025 KB**.

Comment: The `scale` parameter is a scam; used to move the image away from the `1:1` scale; in this case the image appears in higher resolution. When I apply the `dpi` parameter, the bit depth remains fixed at 32, but the `dpi` value does not appear in the properties.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. At this point I'm think about copying text (as you type) into element with display none and just scale it there as much as I need.

Comment: Just to confirm, cloning everything to another (bigger) div indeed worked. It doesn't feel good to do it this way, but at least it works... Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone having the same issue as I; Try dividing your target size by the width of the source size, and then use that value as your scale. To clarify:

```
{
  width: 1080,
  height: 1080,
  scale: 1
}
```

The code above would render a 1080x1080 image, however the actual html content would be contained to 348x348(source size) and surrounded by whitespace.

Instead I divided target/source (1080/348) and got 3.10344828. So, instead of setting the width and height I simply set the scale to 3.10344828 and the image outputted a perfect 1080x1080 image.

```
{
  /*no width no height set*/
  scale: 3.10344828
}
```